# How does Windows acquire drivers for new devices

Tags: windows, driver, device-manager

I was just wondering if anyone could explain to me exactly how Windows goes about downloading or extracting drivers for new devices (like gpu's and usb's) on first time setup.

For Example I got a new USB Wifi Adapter and when I plugged it in, Windows did its thing, device manager pops up "Installing Device Software" (or something like that) and then it just works...
Are the driver files stored on the actual devices (if so is there a certain protocol i can lookup) or does microsoft have a database or something that it references from... idk.

So how does Windows actually acquire the driver files for new devices when they're not yet installed? (Not to mention even without an internet connection..)

Thanks :)

BTW Sorry if this particular question isn't a programming one but I will however use the answer in a program im writing.

Comment: read [Overview of the Driver Selection Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/overview-of-the-driver-selection-process) and [Where Windows Searches for Drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/where-setup-searches-for-drivers) also [How Windows determines the most suitable device driver to install during Setup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/279112/how-windows-determines-the-most-suitable-device-driver-to-install-duri)